# Count([Table].Field), Where([Table].Field = Variable) not returning zero (0)

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that holds responses given to a multiple-choice survey.

The fields in the table are: `[ID] [TERM] [INSTRUCTOR] [CRN] [Q01] [Q02]...[Q24]`.

Each row/record represents an individual's responses to a set of 24 multiple-choice questions (responses are recorded as variables `[A, B, C, D, E, N]`).
[image: Example of table layout]

I need to have a query pull the number of each response (A-N) chosen for each question for each instructor and course number (CRN). [image: Example of Desired Output]

I can write a query that counts each response included for each instructor, one question (field) at a time, but it does not return a zero (0) if a given letter is not selected by the person completing the survey.

I did try `Nz(COUNT([TABLE].FIELD),0)`, but if there's nothing to count, there's not even a NULL to return as zero.

```
SELECT [Department Question List].[Question Number], [Dept Eval Responses].INSTRUCTOR, 
    [Dept Eval Responses].[BANNER TERM], [Dept Eval Responses].CRN, 
    [Dept Eval Responses].Q01_Response AS RESPONSE, 
    Count([Dept Eval Responses].Q01_Response) AS [RESPONSE COUNT]
FROM [Department Question List], [Dept Eval Responses]
WHERE ((([Department Question List].[Question Number])="Q01"))
GROUP BY [Department Question List].[Question Number], 
    [Dept Eval Responses].INSTRUCTOR, [Dept Eval Responses].[BANNER TERM],
    [Dept Eval Responses].COURSE, [Dept Eval Responses].SECTION, [Dept Eval Responses].CRN, 
    [Dept Eval Responses].Q01_Response
ORDER BY [Dept Eval Responses].INSTRUCTOR, [Dept Eval Responses].[BANNER TERM],
    [Dept Eval Responses].COURSE, [Dept Eval Responses].SECTION, 
    [Dept Eval Responses].Q01_Response;
```

Comment: I think if you spend a few more minutes, you could format your question a little bit easier and then people would be more likely to try to understand what you're asking, and possibly even respond.

Comment: The intent of your question is apparent... you want a table of question-answer counts. But your example layout does not fully describe the query's FROM sources.  I suppose that [Department Question List] must be some sort of pivot table?  Or perhaps you are using auxiliary tables to store question numbers in rows that match question columns?  In that case, the tables are not fully normalized and getting the final result may require stitching together many queries. Consider editing and formatting your question like ashleedawg suggests and including more detail about the table structure.

Comment: Start by normalizing the table. Your question currently is double-barreled, you need to normalize first before you're going to do anything reasonable with queries

Comment: With SQL you need  a crosstab query.  If you instead dump the data into Excel, you need a simple pivot table.